# How do I get state from one slice to another? Redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm making a small MERN application and I'm interested in how to transfer a user from authSlice, which has a user object where I place the user when fetching, to profileSlice? Because in profileSlice I want to have logic about follow / unfollow. But I need a user to manipulate it.

```
const initialState = {
  user: null,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  isSuccessVerify: false,
  message: '',
  isAuthenticated: false,
  loadingUser: true,
};

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: state => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isError = false;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.message = '';
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
......................
 
    // Login
    [login.pending]: state => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
    },
    [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.user = action.payload.user;
    },
    [login.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.message = action.payload;
    },
.................
});
```

I want to use that user I put in the authSlice initial state to profileSlice. How i can do this?

Comment: You can dispatch the action of profileSlice in which you can set user state of profileSlice too when you have fetched the results successfully